# Spades rules on trumping in after spades are broken

Tags: spades

In Spades after spades are broken can any player trump in even if he has the suite that was led?  Or does he have to be out of the suite that was led before he can trump?

Answer (score 8):

As in most traditional trick-taking games, a player *must* follow suit if able. Breaking spades only allows a player to *lead* spades, i.e. to play a spade as the first card of a trick. Players can only play a spade on a non-spade trick if they have no cards of the led suit.